An inconsistency in the CHSH inequality
I saw this paper recently https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.01275
Correct me if Im wrong, but in short it says that all the experimental data so far cannot be used to dismiss local hidden variable theories. They claim that in an actual experiment the four correlation operators that make up the CHSH inequality are applied on different particles, each with its own random variable. This increases the maximum value attainable by a local hidden variable theory from 2 to 4, which cannot be violated using quantum theory.
The paper makes sense to me and it feels like an extremely obvious thing that people should have noticed years ago. I do not follow research on quantum foundations, so I'm curious what people working in this field think of it.
Also thinking about the implications of this observation it seems to me that no correlations that uses local measurements can be used to disprove a local hidden variable model. Does this follow from this work?

Look that by this reasoning, there should be no correlation at all. If the four measurements are explainable by four different random variables $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4$ and they all prepared independently, it makes no sense in to search for correlations.
Bell experiments are prepare-and-measure experiments, where we have a source preparing a quantum system (like a pair of entangled electrons) and distributing it over two or many parties where measurements will be realized. Of course there are many rounds of measurements, where the results are registered and we build a table of results, like
| Round | A1B1 | A2B1 | A2B1 | A2B2 |
|-------|------|------|------|------|
|   1   | +1   |      |      |      |
|   2   |      |      | +1   |      |
|   …   |      |      |      |      |

Observe that in each round, a pair is chosen to be measured and it value is registered. At the final we can compute the average value and we know, by the law of large numbers, that it will be near the average value of such random variables.
In each round, a new system is prepared and distributed. To apply the law of large numbers, of course we assume that each round is independent of previous rounds, i.e., the system has no memory of what happened before. We have no reason to assume that $A_1$ could be attributed the same value in two different rounds, for example it could happen that a measurement of $A_1B_1$ returns $-1$ in a round, and a measurement of $A_1B_2$, $A_2B_1$ and $A_2B_2$ all gives $+1$ in next rounds, with should be impossible if the random variables all have the same values for different rounds. But any of these considerations is a problem for Bell theorem.
The existence of classical hidden variables constrain the expectation values of the measured quantities. We have no access of such $\lambda$, so if we assume that it exists, we should assume that the observed values and the estimated averages $\langle A_iB_j\rangle$ comes from an average of such variables, i.e.,
$$
\langle A_iB_j\rangle = \int  A_i(\lambda)B_j(\lambda) p(\lambda)d\lambda.
$$
Look that the random variable giving the $A_i$ value is the same giving $B_j$ value, because it is being measured in the same round, i.e., over an entangled pair of electrons for example. The random variable doesn't need to be the same each round, but should be the same for each measurement in the pair that are being measured.
The flaw in this article is a false causal implication. Basically it is saying that "the four measurements are realized over four different systems" which is true, but "it implies four different random variables", which is false. It would be at most two different random variables, say $\lambda_k$ in round $k$ and $\lambda_l$ in round $l$, but after that we should average over rounds and it would imply averaging over such random variables.
Four different independent measurements over four different and independent hidden random variables does not observe any correlation at all and also does not explain quantum theory, since we know that there is correlations.
Why each measurement in a pair receive the same random variable for each round
Let's say it will be measured $A_iB_j$ many times and their values will be explained by hidden variables $\lambda_{A}$ and $\lambda_{B}$, in principle different.
$$
\langle A_iB_j\rangle = \int  A_i(\lambda_A)B_j(\lambda_B) p(\lambda_A,\lambda_B)d\lambda_A d\lambda_B.
$$
Now if these hidden variables are independent, i.e., $p(\lambda_A,\lambda_B)=p(\lambda_A)p(\lambda_B)$, there would be no correlation between these measurements and the expectation value will factorize.
$$
\langle A_iB_j\rangle = 
\langle A_i\rangle\langle B_j\rangle 
$$
which is not what we want, since we observe correlations. Now, if they are not independent, this model in fact is a special case of the model
$$
\langle A_iB_j\rangle = \int  A_i(\lambda_A,\lambda_B)B_j(\lambda_A,\lambda_B) p(\lambda_A,\lambda_B)d\lambda_A d\lambda_B
$$
i.e., where both measurements depends on both variables. This model is more strong and has more chance to explain the experiment, despite being local. But note that if we identify $\lambda= (\lambda_A,\lambda_B$, it returns to
$$
\langle A_iB_j\rangle = \int  A_i(\lambda)B_j(\lambda) p(\lambda)d\lambda.
$$
That is the Bell model. This shows that considering one hidden variable for the pair is not a lack of generality, but the opposite: we are considering the most general explanation with shared random classical variable possible and even with this, we cannot explain all quantum correlations.

« The random variable doesn't need to be the same each round, but should be the same for each measurement in the pair that are being measured. » Why? I don’t remember this being necessary. You mean that the random variable should have the same law for the two particles?

I'll edit it and explain it in more details ...

Only if you have the time :) I actually don’t think it is very important for the current matter.

Aaaaaah ok I get what you meant (I did not understand that by « random variable », you were referring to the hidden variables). Yes, yes, I agree. As a side comment, the explanation you provide is why I think some people are mistaken: the « locality » in all this is not about one particle not being able to « feel » what the value of the (nonsensical) local hidden variable of the other particle, it’s just about each particle not knowing which measurement is made on the other. Good job!


The flaw in this article is a false causal implication. Basically it is saying that "the four measurements are realized over four different systems" which is true, but "it implies four different random variables", which is false.

Let me see if I understand it.
If the starting assumption is that different particles have different hidden variables then this is true right?

The point is that it doesn't matter. Different particles could have different hidden variables, no problem. The only thing is important is that Alice measurement and Bob measurement should be correlated, so these hidden variables should be correlated.

What’s important about Bell inequalities is the following:

assume that the universe satisfies some property formulated in precise mathematical terms that you may (or not) interpret as « local realism »
derive inequalities
perform experiments
if the experiments violates the inequality, conclude that the mathematical assumption cannot describe the experiment.

That’s it.
I think the author says: we could have ruled out the assumptions from the start (and the argument is basically « because when dealing with different particles, it’s obvious that these assumptions are wrong »)) without performing any experiment, so, just jump to step 4 without going through steps 1, 2, 3. I think the author should have put more emphasis on this instead of reproving the CHSH inequality.
Therefore, I think the paper just contains an obvious objection to the subject that has already be refuted a lot of times (I don’t have a reference in mind, but the refutation can be found in the answer above).
I should say that I think the author is right when he puts emphasis on the fact that the argumentation should be cautious about the fact that the experiments are statistical, perform measurements on different particles, etc. because this is a crucial point in the argument.

Just to add to the good answers by @Ruffolo and @Plop:
Shocker: there is actually nothing special about CHSH itself other than it highlights the difference between local realistic (LR) predictions and those of QM. There are many angle settings that rule out LR. For photons, 120 degrees is an example. LR predicts >.33, QM predicts .25 in agreement with experiment.
This is simply a variation of the original Bell argument which shows the tension between LR and QM. CHSH is one of those. It is a complete waste of brain cycles to write a (flawed) paper against CHSH, you need to disprove Bell itself to accomplish the author’s intended goal. Papers purporting to do that are a dime a dozen. (See for example the works of Hans De Raedt et al, Joy Christian, none of which have any acceptance is the community.)
In addition: a major flaw of the OP cited paper is the failure to account for perfect correlations. Whenever hidden variables are introduced, you must also explain 100% correlation/anti-correlation at all common angles. And further, you need to explain perfect correlations between entangled pairs that have never existed in a common light cone (created by remote entanglement swapping). How can a local theory explain identical hidden variables in distant (nonlocal) particles?
The upshot is: this paper is mostly sleight of hand, and offers nothing new in the genre.
